# why won't my epson wf-2540 work

Tags: printing, epson

My Epson WF-2540 will not work in Ubuntu.  The printer is recognized, and settings all appear to be correct.  Whenever I try to print something, the print job gets added to a number of other jobs-up to 15 jobs now.  However, I do not see theses jobs accumulated in the print que.

Comment: I should mention that I am double booting.  My Windows operating system is Vista Home Premium.  The printer, copier, and scanner all work in Vista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having this problem too, I found one solution.  Go to http://localhost:631/. This is the CUPS 1.7.2 site where you will manually register your printer. When you get to the site, click on the Printers tab; you may very well see your printer listed here, but it may not have been registered automatically. Weather you see it listed or not, click on the Administration tab and enter your printer information. (My printer was listed when I clicked on the Printer tab, and it was also recognized by Ubuntu, and th settings were all correct, but it still would not print because it was not registered automatically.) After you finish entering your printer information, your printer may very well start working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Epson Connect: Email Print. This will allow you to send files to your printer in the form of an email. A guide for that is available [here](https://www.epsonconnect.com/guide/en/html/uses_1.htm).

Comment: I am actually aware of this.  However, it does not help me because much of what I print can't be emailed.  I do a great deal of printing using eBay's USPS shipping services.  These labels cannot be emailed--it would also be way too time consuming if they could be.